# What is the meaning of graph singal for graph constructed from correlation matrix?

Tags: graphical-model, graph-theory, signal-processing, laplace-approximation

In the highly cited paper "The Emerging Field of Signal Processing on Graphs", the authors defined graph singal for a graph of N vertices as a vector of length N, with each element of the vector corresponding to a scalar value associated with one of the N vertices.

Graph Laplacian is then defined as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

The paper is unique in defining graph Laplacian as above rather than from D - A. The introduction of the concept of graph singal is particularly helpful for helping understand the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of graph Laplacian matrix. As shown in the screenshot below, there is less smoothness for graph Laplacian eigenvector with larger eigenvalue than the eigenvector with smaller eigenvalue. Graph singal in Fig2a is more smooth (smaller eigenvalue) and in Fig2c is less smooth (larger eigenvalue).
[image]

Equation 4 of the paper also provides method to construct graph singal from its decompositions. Graphs signal on vertex i is the weighted sum of the ith element of each graph Laplacian eigenvector, with the weight being some kernel function of the relevant eigenvalue. This paper used heat kenel e^(-5*lambda_l) for the lth eigenvalue as the weight for the lth eigenvector.
[image]

From equation 4 above, I know how graph singal at each vertex can be derived from graph Laplcaian matrix. **What is the meaning of graph signal at each vertex?**

Here is an example with which I wish to understand the meaning of graph singal:
100 students' exam scores on 50 courses are arranged to data of 100 rows and 50 columns. A correlation matrix of 50*50 is then constructed, with each element representing correlation of scores for every two courses. This corresponds to a fully connected graph of 50 nodes, with edge strength encoded by the correlation matrix. According to the paper, graph signal is a column vector of length 50, with each course being assigned a single scalar graph signal value. But there are in fact 100 values for each course coming from the 100 students. **I want to ask how is the single graph signal value associated with each course determined?** I know from equation 4 that the value can be constructed from graph laplacian eigenvectors and eigenvalues. But I think graph signal should exist in the first place, which can be decomposed. From eq4, I only know how to reconstruct graph singal but that probaly does not directly tell me what a graph signal is. I want to understand graph signal from first principle, rather than merely knowing that it can be reconstructed from inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Perhaps the score is eigenvector centrality.